# how can I do inverse of self-reference with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the user model like :

```
  has_many :users, class_name: 'User'
  belongs_to :master_user, class_name: 'User', optional: true, inverse_of: :users
```

I Would like to find :

User.first.master_user it's ok

MasterUser.users but  get an error : "NameError: uninitialized constant MasterUser"

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of how to properly setup a self-referential association with a bit less confusing naming:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :manager
    class_name: 'User', # requied here since it cannot be derided from the name
    optional: true,
    inverse_of: :subordinates
  has_many :subordinates,
    class_name: 'User',  # requied here since it cannot be derided from the name
    foreign_key: :manager_id, # what column on the users table should we join
    inverse_of: :manager
end
```

"Managers" here are not a separate class. While you could use single table inheritance to that purpose you should probally get the basics figured out first. Even if you did have a `MasterUser` class you would get `NoMethodError` since you're calling `.users` on the class and not an instance of the class - that will never work and is a very common beginner misstake.

Note that this strictly speaking would actually work without the `inverse_of:` option which is really just used to explicity set [the two way binding in memory](https://www.viget.com/articles/exploring-the-inverse-of-option-on-rails-model-associations/).

So in your case it should look like:

```ruby
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # class_name isn't required since it can be derided from the name
  has_many :users, 
    foreign_key: :master_user_id,
    inverse_of: :master_user
  belongs_to :master_user, 
    class_name: 'User', # requied here since it cannot be derided from the name
    optional: true, 
    inverse_of: :users
end
```

Note that the users table must have a `master_user_id` column.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting that error because you have not defined a `MasterUser` model. I am guessing you only have a `User` model as described in your question. If you want to find the users belonging to a "master_user" then you need to find a "master_user" first, then request its users. It would look something like this:

```
user_with_a_master = User.where.not(master_user_id: nil).first
master             = user_with_a_master.master_user
master_users       = master.users
```

Comment: ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column users.user_id does not exist

Comment: None of my code should be looking for a `user_id` column on the `users` table. Something else you have is causing that. Can you update your question with the schema of the relevant tables? And maybe provide more of your User model, including the opening definition?